# Redirect site. URL:port-number

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting, webmail

Can I redirect this:

```
http://example.com:2095/logout/?locale=es
```

To

```
http://subdomain.example.com
```

It's to customize the log-out page of a webmail. Have no root access.

The logout link comes from the cpanel webmail logout.

Typing the same logout URL in the browser, or getting logout by webmail link takes to the same logout page (no results in redirecting with .htaccess). (Other URL redirects works fine)

Hostgator support didn't give any concrete info about redirecting from ports 2095 or 2096. Basically I was told that they're are used for webmail and I should not be trying to customize anything about it.

Comment: In htaccess in the document root :





    `RewriteEngine on


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2095$
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /logout/\?locale=es
    RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.example.com [L,R]`